# Get feature from map using Mapbox

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I am using polygon shape files and I want to turn on and off visibility of some features on the map. However, I cannot reach to the properties of the features. I tried the code below, but it does not go through the loop. What should I do?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>getMap</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.2/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.2/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v0.0.4/leaflet.fullscreen.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v0.0.4/Leaflet.fullscreen.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-hash/v0.2.1/leaflet-hash.js'></script>
<div id='map'>
</div>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWVsYm91cm5ldW5pIiwiYSI6ImNpZzc4YmNvdTBrdzR0dWx6cW1tZG00d2UifQ.T4kFqEpykbTCepilYVeL_g';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', {attributionControl: true});
var featureLayer =     L.mapbox.featureLayer('melbourneuni.hetjfw29').addTo(map);
featureLayer.on('ready', function(){
// navigate the GeoJSON to get to the coordinates
var geojson = this.getGeoJSON();});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `var geojson = this.getGeoJSON()`, like

```
featureLayer.on('ready', function(e){
    var geojson = this.getGeoJSON()
    // which returns featureCollection, iterate through `geojson.features` array next as you need
});
```

Comment: What do you mean it does not go through the loop? I meant that you need to use a vanilla JS for loop, or underscore's _.each

Comment: I didn't write the code for the loop in my example because the problem in your original code example was that you were trying to grab the GeoJSON from an incorrect location(`e.target`), not that a loop was configured incorrectly. –

Comment: Can you show me the code that triggers the error? Or better yet a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm getting a `{"message":"Tileset does not exist"}` response your features.json call. Are you seeing the same thing in your testing?check your JS console.

Comment: I have added .geojson file as a map, but data could not be loaded. Can you check the code again? What I am missing?

Comment: I pasted your code into a fiddle, and it still fails - https://jsfiddle.net/cvat1cnp/ This is the up to date code right? - It still fails on grabbing the features.

Comment: It's throwing a `{"message":"Markers do not exist"}` response from features.json.